# how to find its period?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, periodic-functions

I have this function $T(x)=x+4B \pmod A$. I want to solve the congruence for the smallest positive $n$,
$T^{n} (x)=x \pmod A$.
How to solve it and find its period?

To solve it, what I did is by iteration I have $T^{n} (x)=x+4nB$.
Then I found that the $x$ can be cancelled out which is 
$$T^{n}(x)-x \pmod A=x+4nB-x \pmod A=4nB \pmod A.$$ How can I give comment on this one and find its period? I know the period is $A$ but I am not sure how to give a good explanation about this.

Thank you.

Comment: The smallest period is not always $A$. If $\gcd(4B,A)>1$ you will have smaller periods. e.g. for $B=1, A=12$ the cylce is $$x \rightarrow x+4 \rightarrow x+8 \rightarrow x $$

Comment: If I want to consider $gcd (A,B)=1$, the period will always A right?

Comment: No, you have to consider the complete $\gcd(4B, A)$. In my example you have $\gcd(B,A)=\gcd(1,12)=1$ but $\gcd(4,12)>1$

Answer (score 2):

This is the smallest $n$ such that $4nB$  is a multiple of $A$. Thus $4nB$ is the l.c.m. of $A$ and $4B$. There's a well-known formula which links l.c.m.  and g.c.d.:
$$\operatorname{lcm}(A, 4B)\cdot\gcd(A, 4B)=A\cdot4B,$$
hence $$n=\frac{A}{\gcd(A,4B)}.$$

Comment: This should be $n=\frac{A}{\gcd(A,4B)}\cdot\,$ This follows from your first line if you plugin $\mathrm{lcm}(A,4B)=4nB$.

Comment: If I consider $gcd(A,B)=1$, do you mean that the period is $n=4B / gcd(A,4B)$?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I messed up in my mental computation.It's corrected now. Thanks for pointing it.